# schema method this keyword is not working

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So I am trying to have a schema function that uses validates a password with a hashed version but the this keyword is not working

```
userSchema.methods.validPassword = (pwd)=>{
  const userPwd = this.password;
  console.log(userPwd+' '+pwd);
  const pass = bcrypt.compareSync(pwd, userPwd);
  return pass;
};
```

the userPwd is returning undefined ?
my fix is -

```
userSchema.methods.validPassword = (user,pwd)=>{
  const userPwd = user.password;
  console.log(userPwd+' '+pwd);
  const pass = bcrypt.compareSync(pwd, userPwd);
  return pass;
};
```

this is how I used the method -

```
if(result.validPassword(result,req.body.password)){
          res.redirect('/imgs')
        }else{
          console.log('User password incorrect');
          res.send('G u got da pass wrong')
        }
```

but I would like to know why the this didn't work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you show how you're calling it as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
userSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function (enteredPassword) {
    return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password);
};
```

Why are you using compareSync?

Example of it being used in a user controller on the server...

```
// @desc    Auth user & get token
// @route   POST /api/users/login
// @access  Public
const authUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    const user = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (user && (await user.matchPassword(password))) {
        res.json({
            _id: user._id,
            name: user.name,
            email: user.email,
            isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
            token: generateToken(user._id),
        });
    } else {
        res.status(401);
        throw new Error("Invalid email or password");
    }
});
```